# Get screen width SASS

Tags: css, sass

```
$margin-between-rows: 10px;

@mixin row-cols($count) {
 $margin-total: $margin-between-rows * ($count - 1);
  $width-per-item: percentage(divide((screen - $margin-total), $count));
  > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: percentage(divide(1, $count));
    margin-right: $margin-between-rows;
    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do:
basically we have something like `width: percentage(divide(1, $count));`, but I need to add margin between rows. Code that I attached earlier can't do it because if I change "screen" to "1" - the subtraction result will be below 0. If I leave "screen" there is an `Error: Undefined operation "screen-0px > 0".`

What do I do so that margin counts into width of row? Can I do it w\o using JS?

Comment: Have you tried using 100% instead of `screen`?